# CHAR Compare is right, even when it's wrong

Tags: c++, arduino

first im new at c++ programming and at the moment im stuck in a maybe very easy problem.
I thought, after get the other stuff working and in my oppinion, much harder, i will implement a little string compare and im are ready, ha ha...
I tryed to figure out what is the problem and working on it since hours...

I try to make a string compare.
With serial print i see the correct letters. For Example i compare "A" and "B".
My Problem is, that this compare is right, even when it's wrong.

```
bool debug = true;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
if (debug) { Serial.begin(9600); }; // Initialize serial communications with the PC
}

void loop() {
    int result;

    char myWord[6] = "#VOGEL";
    char wordBuff[5];
    char wordLetter;
    char letterBuff;

    // I do this here, because actually i get all values from two RFID Reader
    strncpy( wordBuff, &myWord[1], 5 );
    wordBuff[5] = '\0';
    
    for (int fieldNr = 0; fieldNr < 5; fieldNr++)
    {
      wordLetter = wordBuff[fieldNr];
      letterBuff = 'L';


        result = strcmp(letterBuff,wordLetter); // Should be every time wrong? But it is sometimes true?
              
        if ( result == 0)
        {
          if(debug){  Serial.print(F("Right Field: "));Serial.println(fieldNr);
          Serial.print(F(" LetterA: "));Serial.print(wordLetter);Serial.println(F("#")); 
          Serial.print(F(" LetterB: "));Serial.print(letterBuff);Serial.println(F("#"));}
        }
        else
        {
          if(debug){  Serial.print(F("Wrong Field: "));Serial.println(fieldNr);
          Serial.print(F(" LetterA: "));Serial.print(wordLetter);Serial.println(F("#")); 
          Serial.print(F(" LetterB: "));Serial.print(letterBuff);Serial.println(F("#"));}
        }
      }
    delay(1000); //NUR für TESTZWECKE
}
```

Comment: Your buffer sizes are off. If this is C++, why do you use low-level char array manipulation instead of `std::string`?

Comment: `wordLetter` and `letterBuff` are characters, `strcmp` is used to compare strings. To compare characters a simple `==` will suffice.

Comment: Does it even compile? [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) has no overload for `char`s.

Comment: You're writing outside the array bounds with `wordBuff[5] = '\0';`. The highest index is `wordBuff[4]`.

Comment: `char myWord[6] = "#VOGEL";` should be a "too many initializers" compilation error.

Comment: Change it to == was the solution, that easy. Tried it with std but on the Arduino this will not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*strcmp* is only for const char *, not a single char like you are using it.

I don't remember if Arduino permits you to use the std::string but in case just use it.
It introduce you lot more methods for string handling. Like s.find(c) that return directly the position of the char in the string.

By the way, to compare 2 char, in your example, just use a simple:

```
if(c1 == c2)
  ...
else
  ...
```

It should solve it.